# How to randomly pick and replace a value from a template-string's options-pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, random, replace

Aim:extract sentences or paragraphs from the given syntax structure. Pick any random word/phrase between “{” & “}” separated by “|” and make one realistic output.

Input:

```
{Hi|Hello|Hola} @name, Good {Morning|Evening}. {I am|We are} very {glad|hapy) that you came here {to meet us.
```

Output1: Hi abc Good Morning, I am very glad that you came here to meet us.

Output2: Hola abc Good Evening, I am very happy that you came here to meet us.

Output3: Hello abc Good Morning, We are very glad that you came here to meet us.

```js
function extract([beg, end]) {
  const matcher = new RegExp(`${beg}(.*?)${end}`,'gm');
  const normalise = (str) => str.slice(beg.length,end.length*-1);
  return function(str) {
      return str.match(matcher).map(normalise);
  }
}
var str = "{Hi|Hello|Hola} @name, Good {Morning|Evening}. {I am|We are} very {glad|hapy) that you came here {to meet us."
const stringExtractor = extract(['{','}']);
const stuffIneed = stringExtractor(str)
```

```
I have extract the words between {} in array and now trying to compare and replace them
```

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: You are more likely to receive help if you show an attempt to solve the problem. Please share your code, even if it is not working correctly.

Comment: function extract([beg, end]) {
  const matcher = new RegExp(`${beg}(.*?)${end}`,'gm');
  const normalise = (str) => str.slice(beg.length,end.length*-1);
  return function(str) {
      return str.match(matcher).map(normalise);
  }
}

const stringExtractor = extract(['{','}']);
const stuffIneed = stringExtractor(str)

output: Hi|Hello|Hola,Morning|Evening,I am|We are

I have extract the words between {} in array and now trying to compare and replace them

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your attempt there.

Comment: @PallaviPatil ... The OP might check out another answer which does everything within a single replace task via a sole regex and its related replacement function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution is by using regular expressions
Here is a code snippet

I isolated the `{...}` parts, then split them by `|`, used random and then replaced the original `{...}` part with the random element

```js
let t = '{Hi|Hello|Hola} @name, Good {Morning|Evening}. {I am|We are} very {glad|hapy} that you came here to meet us.'
let matches = t.match(/{([A-Z ](\|*))*}/gi)

for (const match of matches) {
  let splt = match.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split('|')
  t = t.replace(match, splt[Math.floor(Math.random() * splt.length)])
}

console.log(t)
```

Second approach using a method

```js
let t = '{Hi|Hello|Hola} @name, Good {Morning|Evening}. {I am|We are} very {glad|hapy} that you came here to meet us.'

function printSentence(sentence) {
 let matches = t.match(/{([A-Z ](\|*))*}/gi)

  for (const match of matches) {
    let splt = match.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split('|')
    sentence = sentence.replace(match, splt[Math.floor(Math.random() * splt.length)])
  }

  console.log(sentence)
}


printSentence(t)
printSentence(t)
printSentence(t)
```

Comment: ok use a for loop

Comment: @PallaviPatil i updated my answer with a second snippet that outputs 3 sentences

Comment: you didnt specify that in your question. can you please update your question with exactly what you want to achieve? you never mentioned an array

Comment: so why did you accept my answer and then reverted it? what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

One would go for [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex and a related replacement function where one implements the access of the provided template string's text alternatives as e.g. `options`.

I personally would choose a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which [captures](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) the `options` related data directly. Something like ... [`/\{([^}]+)\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/zXJS1s/2) ... or same with a [named capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) ... [`/\{(?<options>[^}]+)\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/zXJS1s/1).

- The regex is going to match

  - `\{` ... a single opening brace ... followed by ...
  - `([^}]+)` ... at least one character which is not a closing brace ... followed by ...
  - `\}` ... a single closing brace.
- Since the character sequence of the second point is enclosed by parenthesis `( ... )` it will be captured/remembered. One also could go for a named capturing group where one just needs to declare the group name ...  `(?<options> ... )`

The related [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement) will get passed every regex result as parameters of following form `[match, options, offset, string, groups]` where `options` is the sole captured group and `match` is the entire matching string. In our case everything except `options` can be ignored.

- `options` needs to be [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) at every pipe character ...
- ... which then gives the opportunity to [`random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)ly pick a string from the just split array.
- This string is both the replacement function's return value and thus the value which replaces the regular expressions entire match.

```js
const sampleTemplate =
  `{Hi|Hello|Hola} @name, Good {Morning|Evening}. {I am|We are} very {glad|hapy} that you came here to meet us.`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/zXJS1s/2]
const regXReplacementOptions = /\{([^}]+)\}/g;

function pickRandomOption(match, options) {
  options = options.split('|');
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
}
console.log([

  sampleTemplate
    .replace(regXReplacementOptions, pickRandomOption),

  sampleTemplate
    .replace(regXReplacementOptions, pickRandomOption),

  sampleTemplate
    .replace(regXReplacementOptions, pickRandomOption),

].join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```